# Call javascript function on dropdownextender closing

Tags: asp.net, animation, dropdownextender

I'm developing a `Multi-select dropdown list` for that i used `Ajax Drop-down extender`.

## Code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDisplay" runat="server" CssClass="tb10" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Panel ID="DropPanel" runat="server" CssClass="ContextMenuPanel" 
        Width="280px" style="display :none;visibility: hidden;padding-bottom:-1px;
        margin-top:-28px;margin-left:0px;background-color:#F5F5F5;overflow:hidden;
        height:auto;min-height:100px;max-height:300px;max-width:350px;" >
    <div id="CombClose" style="padding-right:2px;color:#FFFFFF;text-align:right;cursor:pointer;height:35px;background-color:#507CD1;width:100%;" runat="server" >Close</div>
    <br />
    <div runat="server" id="listDiv" style="padding-bottom:-1px;margin-top:-28px; 
        margin-left:0px;background-color:#F5F5F5;overflow-Y:auto;overflow-X:hidden;
        height:200px;max-height:265px;max-width:350px;" >
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkList" runat="server" CssClass="Chklist" OnSelectedIndexChanged="chkList_SelectedIndexChanged" > 
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
        <asp:ListBox ID="list" runat="server">
        </asp:ListBox>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
<ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtender runat="server" ID="DDE" TargetControlID="txtDisplay" 
    DropDownControlID="DropPanel" HighlightBorderColor="Transparent" OnClientPopup="OnClientPopup" >
    <Animations>
        <OnShow>
            <Sequence>          
                <HideAction Visible="true" />                                          
                <FadeIn  Duration=".5" Fps="10" />         
            </Sequence>
        </OnShow>
        <OnHide>
            <Sequence>                       
                <FadeOut Duration=".5" Fps="10" />
                <HideAction Visible="false" />
                <StyleAction Attribute="display" Value="none"/>
            </Sequence>
        </OnHide>
    </Animations>
</ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtender>
```

Now i need to call a java-script function on drop-down extender closing.
Can any one guide me how can i do that.
Here I'm using animation is there any way to call any java-script function on `OnHide`.
Plz guid me if there is any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got a solution how can i call java-script function on `dropdownextender` closing.
We can call javascript function by using this.

```
<ScriptAction Script="alert('Dropdown is colsing');" />
```

### Complete code

```
<ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtender runat="server" ID="DDE" TargetControlID="txtDisplay" 
DropDownControlID="DropPanel" HighlightBorderColor="Transparent" OnClientPopup="OnClientPopup" >
<Animations>
    <OnShow>
        <Sequence>          
            <HideAction Visible="true" />                                          
            <FadeIn  Duration=".5" Fps="10" />         
        </Sequence>
    </OnShow>
    <OnHide>
        <Sequence>                       
            <FadeOut Duration=".5" Fps="10" />
            <HideAction Visible="false" />
            <StyleAction Attribute="display" Value="none"/>
            <ScriptAction Script="alert('Dropdown is colsing');" />
        </Sequence>
    </OnHide>
</Animations>
</ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtender>
```

Now my problem is solved.